# model value required when using preload

Tags: go, go-gorm, preload

When I run tx.Preload("Tags"), get error: "model value required when using preload"

```
tx *gorm.DB 
tx = tx.Preload("Tags").Where(filter)   //error comes from here.
var test  []*models.Test 
//do something here.
tx.Find(&test)
```

before this, these below code works fine.

```
tx *gorm.DB 
var test  []*models.Test 
tx.Preload("Tags").Where(filter).Find(&test)
```

Comment: what are you doing in `//do something here` also, how are you setting the `tx` value?

Comment: Hi, please share more because it's hard to tell what's went wrong, thanks!